# Labeling only a part of the attribute value of a string column in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, ysld

I am looking for a solution for labeling points based on an string attribute value in my table in a way that it shows only a portion of the attribute value in GeoServer. I am using ysld (sld) styling. The idea is that wherever there is an 'AND' in the string, the label should show only the portion before the 'AND'. For example in the table below there are few rows with values that have AND in them.

[image]

When the style is applied to this table it should show only 'ABC' for row 1, 'GHIJ' for row 2, and so on.
Below is the style I have without the split in the attribute

```
  - filter: ${name <> 'OWNER INFO NA'}
    scale: [min, 1067]
    symbolizers:
    - text:
        label: ${name}
        fill-color: '#FFFFFF'
        font-family: DejaVu Sans
        font-size: 10
        font-weight: bold
        anchor: [0.5,0.5]
        rotation: 0
        placement: point
        x-autoWrap: 50
        x-spaceAround: 10
        halo:
          radius: 1.25
          fill-color: '#000000'
          placement: point
```

What should I add in the 'label:' function in the style to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer provides a large number of [functions](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) including [string manipulation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions) ones.

In your case I would look at `strIndexOf` to find where the first space is and `strSubstring` to return just the string upto that value.